# Docker volume file mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I try to replace a file in a docker container by using the following `docker-compose` syntax. But connecting to the `bash` of the container shows me that the file still has the original content. 
My question is: Is it possible to replace existing files in a container or is my syntax wrong?

```
version: "3.3"

services:
...
  app:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/app/tenants.json:/tenants.json:ro
...
```

Comment: Please include all steps needed to reproduce your issue. Show the file before and after, along with if and how you recreated the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. My problem was that my file was actually a folder that was created while I copied the file to the server :(